# Passing complex JSON data jQuery to Action

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery

I have 2 classes that are used to mirror the data from an ajax call. One (**Customer**) contains a property which is name, and the other is an array of **Products**.

```
Public Class Customer
    Private _Name as String
    Private _Products as Product()

    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _Name 
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Products() As Product()
        Get
            Return _Products
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Product())
            _Products= value
        End Set
    End Property
```

and the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '../../Customer/SaveCustomerData',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { "Name": this.Name,
                "Products": [{ "ProductCode": "product 1", "ProductName": "product 1" },
                             { "ProductCode": "product 2", "ProductName": "product 2"}]
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Customer has been saved!");
        }
    });
```

The value for Customer.Name is reflected but the properties of the Products remain nothing while still having a length of 2.

Am I missing something really important here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now you're not passing JSON, you're passing the data as it is, (serialized with [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/))...which looks like this:

```
Name=something&Products%5B0%5D%5BProductCode%5D=product+1&Products%5B0%5D%5BProductName%5D=product+1&Products%5B1%5D%5BProductCode%5D=product+2&Products%5B1%5D%5BProductName%5D=product+2
```

To pass JSON, you need to stringify it, like this:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ "Name": this.Name,
        "Products": [{ "ProductCode": "product 1", "ProductName": "product 1" },
                     { "ProductCode": "product 2", "ProductName": "product 2"}]
       }),
```

Which looks like this:

```
{"Name":"something","Products":[{"ProductCode":"product 1","ProductName":"product 1"},{"ProductCode":"product 2","ProductName":"product 2"}]}
```

Now *that's* something your model can turn back into an object.  For older browsers (< IE8) which don't support native `JSON`, [include `json2.js`](http://www.json.org/js.html) which will emulate the behavior.